# Chrome mixed orientation @page property renders at width of first page

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium, gotenberg

I am working on a report rendering system (using [Gotenberg](https://gotenberg.dev/), but the issue is coming from Chromium). I need the ability to have both landscape and portrait pages in the same PDF report. [Using CSS Named Pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page) seems to be the solution, but when I place a landscape page after a portrait page, the width of the content is limited to the portrait width (though the page does print in landscape).

Here's some example HTML that shows the problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            @page {
                margin: 0.125in;
            }
            @page wide {
                size: landscape;
            }
            div {
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                border: 3px solid red;
                page-break-after: always;
            }
            .landscape {
                page: wide;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="portrait"></div>
        <div class="landscape"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I print this page, you can see that the paper is in landscape orientation, but the content is still limited to portrait width.
[Chrome Print Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EzUu.png)

FWIW, I'm on Chrome Version 116.0.5845.96 (Official Build) (arm64) for M1 Mac, but as I said above, it is replicated in Chromium as well.

I'm really hoping I'm missing something or there's a workaround.